# ERC-1155-NFT token shows balance of 0 on Metamask

Tags: tokens, metamask, etherscan, nft, erc-1155

I have a NFT 1155-Smartcontract, so for each tokenId, the supply is 1.

I am testing on the rinkeby testnet and am having some issues.

The minting itself is working fine, meaning that the successful transaction shows up in MetaMask and Etherscan.
The problem is, that even after manually importing the Smartcontract into MetaMask, it shows me a balance of 0 for this token type.
When I take a look on Etherscan and inspect the [token](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x28bc04deeb35b148133157a5db3e28a5dc9a4c92?a=0x8711c738c188aed8da673e8ef5d3cdc2b3abe921) it tells me that "Filtered by totalSupply(), method returned a 0 value".
I am using the totalSupply() method from OpenZeppelin (ERC1155Supply.sol).

I am unsure what the issue might be since everything looks fine except for the token not showing up on MetaMask. Even calling the balanceOf() method on the contract confirms, that the minter has the token with Id 0.

Any help is appreciated